# Creating inset shadow for river polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, 3d, shadow

I'm trying to accomplish what the image of the two ponds shows as "inset" shading. They called this Bevel effect, which I think was down in Adobe Illustrator. I'm using ArcMap 10.3 without 3D Analyst.

I want to shade a river polygon so it ultimately appears as if it's at a lower elevation then the ground. The closest I've come to that is creating a buffer around it using the Buffer wizard (see image with shaded rivers).

I've also used the move tool through the Layer Properties menu --> Representations. However, this only makes the polygon appear to pop up.

[image: Bevel effect]

[image: ArcGIS Buffer Wizard]

Answer (score 4):

You can do something close using the following steps especially for the first image:

- Go to layer properties of the lake symbol -> Symbology
- Click on the Symbol (Colored Rectangle) to change its properties, as you can see below:

[image]

- Click on Edit Symbol -> Under `Properties Type` Choose `Gradient Fill Symbol`, as you can see below:

[image]

- Right-click `Color Ramp` -> Select `Properties` -> Choose the desired two colors that you want -> Adjust the Bright and Dark colors to get the desired effects
- Press OK (3 times) -> Apply and you can get an output like this:

[image]

[image]